# Sending email with calender invite and html doesn't show correctly

Tags: c#, iphone, email, outlook, icalendar

I'm trying to send a mail containing html with inline images as well as a calender invitation (.ics). I have tested that both elements at least work seperately.

If I use Gmail.com to view the mail it displays all elements correctly. Showing information about the event at the top of the mail and showing the text with images. The issue is that depending on the order that I create the alternateViews, it either works with Outlook or Iphone, it always works with gmail.com/gmailclient but not all three at the same time.

```
        SmtpClient sc = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(IP);
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("demomail@hotmail.com", "bob");

        string mailTo = "client@gmail.com";

        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailTo, "Client Name"));
        msg.Subject = "Send Calendar Appointment Email";
        string mailBody = $"<br><div class=\"dagsordenMødeDato\"> Her er dagsordenen for mødet 10-10-2018 14:45:00 </div><br> <br><ul class=\"dagsordenListe\"><li>Leasing til dig</li><li>Pension</li><li>Garantkunde</li><li>Dine fordele</li></ul><br> <div class=\"bekrivelseAfVedhæftning\">Jeg har vedhæftet et dokument.</div>";
        string icsContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"H:\hjemmelavetICS.ics");
```

If the alternateView for the calender is placed before the alternateView for Html in the code then it works on 'Mail' for iphone

```
        ContentType contype = new ContentType("text/calendar");
        contype.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
        contype.Parameters.Add("name", "Invitation.ics");
        contype.CharSet = "utf-8";
        AlternateView avCal =
            AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(icsContent, contype);
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);




            LinkedResource inlineRådgiver = new LinkedResource(
            @"K:\MEDARBEJDERBILLEDER\Signatur Notes\" + "fn" + ".jpg",
            MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
        inlineRådgiver.ContentId = "raadgiverID";
        inlineRådgiver.ContentType.Name = "Raadgiver.jpg";


        LinkedResource inlineKampagne = new LinkedResource(
            @"K:\MEDARBEJDERBILLEDER\Signatur Notes\" + "Kampagne" + ".jpg",
            MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
        inlineKampagne.ContentId = "kampagneID";
        inlineKampagne.ContentType.Name = "Kampagne.jpg";

        var htmlContentType =
            new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");
        htmlContentType.CharSet = "utf-8";
        string embededHtml =
            "<a href=\"https://www.sparthy.dk/\"><img src=cid:raadgiverID alt=\"medarbejder\"></p></a><a href=\"https://www.sparthy.dk/om-sparekassen/nyheder-generelt/1912-garantmoder-2018\"><img style=\"border: 0;\" src=cid:kampagneID alt=\"kampagne\"></a>";
        string fullHtml = mailBody + embededHtml;
        var avHtmlBody = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(fullHtml, htmlContentType);
        avHtmlBody.LinkedResources.Add(inlineRådgiver);
        avHtmlBody.LinkedResources.Add(inlineKampagne);
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(avHtmlBody);

        sc.Send(msg);
```

However if I add the alternateview for html before the calender then it works for Outlook.

I have been scratching my head over this for a week now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Responsive emails is full of pain. Also, this is more about HTML, bot C#. Try to ask another question with HTML documents you generate in each of variant.

Comment: I have posted another question with both HTML and mime contents of the mails here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697938/mail-with-icalendar-and-html-doesnt-work-on-outlook-and-iphone-mail-simultane

Comment: Want to make sure that the html show correctly if you remove the calendar content of Email?

Comment: @SimonLi No, I could remove the calender content and it would work just fine on all clients. What I'm asking is how to write/structure the code so it'll work both on Iphone and Outlook. As it seems to be working separately under different conditions.

Comment: @ThomasNielsen were you able to solve this issue? I am experiencing the same problem